# Cannot load driver to memory

Tags: windows, kernel-mode, driver

I'm trying to unpack some windows driver but I can't load it to memory. I tried OSRLoader, ProcessHacker and my own loader and all returns ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND at OpenService. What's strange, other drivers works fine.  Unfortunatelly I don't have original dropper, can it be some kind of anti debugging trick? What can be reason?

Comment: for 32-bit drivers there was KmdKit tool by Four-F, have you tried it?

Comment: @AntonKukoba It's 64bit driver but I tried and throws same error :/

Comment: Are there any messages in the Windows Event log about your driver?

Comment: @AntonKukoba Dump: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/E8RmY8Ei)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a filesystem filter driver, it cannot be run just like usual driver by creating a service and then starting it. You need to create inf file and register it properly, only then you'll be able to start its service.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/creating-an-inf-file-for-a-file-system-filter-driver